# Is there a DTLS implementation in JSSE

Tags: java, udp, jsse, dtls

I want to implement a DTLS 1.0 client in Java and after *googling* a bit I found that the [JSSERefGuide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html) says the following:

> The JSSE API is capable of supporting SSL versions 2.0 and 3.0 and TLS
>   version 1.0. These security protocols encapsulate a normal
>   bidirectional stream socket, and the JSSE API adds transparent support
>   for authentication, encryption, and integrity protection. **The JSSE
>   implementation shipped with the JDK supports SSL 3.0, TLS (1.0, 1.1,
>   and 1.2) and DTLS (version 1.0 and 1.2).** It does not implement SSL
>   2.0.

So I thought I could implement it in pure Java without using any library (e.g. BouncyCastle)

But when I try running (and a few other, like DTLSv1.2, DTLSv1...):

```
final SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("DTLSv1.0", "SunJSSE");
```

It throws:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: no such algorithm: DTLSv1.0 for provider SunJSSE
at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getService(GetInstance.java:87)
at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:206)
at javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getInstance(SSLContext.java:199)
```

while for example the following works:

```
final SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2", "SunJSSE");
```

Listing all Security Providers I find no DTLS stuff at all.

So is there actually a DTLS implementation? And if so how are you supposed to use it?

Comment: Good quest6ion. DTLS isn't mentioned in the Standard Names page.

Comment: I think this is a glitch in the website; the docs packages I downloaded several years ago are different here. The table at 'Support Classes and Interfaces' halfway down the page correctly shows only SSL3, TLS1, 1.1, 1.2 for 8 and 7, and for 6 the TLS1.1 and 1.2 are only as of 6u111 and 6u121 (i.e. on the paid plan or OpenJDK). Ditto the 'standard names' at e.g. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#SSLContext et pred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The doc is right and you get an Exception because there is no DTLS protocol :
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#SSLContext

Choosing DTLS comes at the moment of creating the socket, as it will be one of TCP or datagram types. As beginning, it will look like :

```
DatagramSocket s = new DatagramSocket();
...

final SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.0", "SunJSSE");
sslContext.init(null, yourSSLTrustManager, null);

SSLSocketFactory factory = (SSLSocketFactory)sslContext.getSocketFactory();
SSLSocket daSocket = (SSLSocket) factory.createSocket(s, host, port, false);
```

Comment: Thanks, and a follow up question: To use DTLSv1.0 I assume I should use TLSv1.1? (since there is no DTLS based on TLSv1)

Comment: Choosing DTLS comes at the moment of creating the `SSLContext`.

Comment: You're assuming right, RFC 4737 which describes DTLS 1.0 says "Where we do not explicitly call out differences, DTLS is the same as in [TLS11]"

Comment: EJP : no, check again the SSLContext.getInstance(...) methods, it's impossible at this moment. We very seldom see you give the bad answer, thanks for your great work by the way.

Comment: @EugèneAdell the code example you gave does not compile `factory.createSocket` does not accept a `DatagramSocket`. You don't happen to have some code that works? Thanks in advance

Comment: I haven't any code but I can take some time to make tests later. Have a look at the deprecated which is still supposed to work https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#Socket(java.lang.String,%20int,%20boolean)

Comment: Note that if you ask for "TLSv1.0" when calling SSLContext.getInstance, SunJSSE will interpret this as the *maximum* protocol version you want to support. You should generally just ask for "TLS" to let it negotiate the most recent version.

Comment: @NeilMadden is this documented anywhere ? I can't find it.

Comment: Not documented as far as I know. I know it from bitter experience. See the source code: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk/file/61ee15b9a1ac/src/java.base/share/classes/sun/security/ssl/SSLContextImpl.java#l638 Each TLSXXContext only enables protocols up to that version by default.

Comment: @osundbladdid you were able to find a solution?

Comment: @PauloOliveira didn't see your comment until now. No I went with BouncyCastle instead

Answer (score 6):

You can use https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/master/test/jdk/javax/net/ssl/DTLS/DTLSOverDatagram.java (or https://github.com/twosigma/OpenJDK/blob/master/test/jdk/javax/net/ssl/DTLS/DTLSOverDatagram.java , its the same)

For the person which killed my previous answer because of the links: Even if the link breaks this is no problem - because at looking at the link you'll see with ease that DTLSOverDatagram is part of the official open-jdk 11 tests - so even if the link vanishes you can easily find other sources.

While these are tests for the DTLS implementation, with little refactoring this can be used as a base for DTLS over (udp-) datagrams. For both client and server - in fact, they are almost the same.

Answer (score 2):

DTLS is present in JavaSE 9:  [SSLContext Algorithm Names](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/specs/security/standard-names.html#sslcontext-algorithms)

Comment: JEP 219 adds support for DTLS "BUT" according to the JEP does NOT implement the actual transport-specific interfaces (see non-goals #1 of the JEP) (http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/219) So i guess we have to transport the actual data thru a standard DatagramSocket???

Answer (score 0):

Bases on the sample from JDK and many try and error I have written the follow code which works in my use case:

```
public static final int      MAXIMUM_PACKET_SIZE = 1500;
private final DatagramSocket socket;
private final SSLEngine      engine;

public DtlsSocket( @Nonnull DatagramSocket socket, KeyManager km, TrustManager tm, boolean isClient ) {
    try {
        this.socket = socket;

        SSLContext sslCtx = SSLContext.getInstance( "DTLS" );
        KeyManager[] kms = { km };
        TrustManager[] tms = { tm };
        sslCtx.init( kms, tms, null );
        engine = sslCtx.createSSLEngine();
        engine.setNeedClientAuth( true );

        engine.setUseClientMode( isClient );
        SSLParameters paras = engine.getSSLParameters();
        paras.setMaximumPacketSize( MAXIMUM_PACKET_SIZE );
        engine.setSSLParameters( paras );

        engine.beginHandshake();

        byte[] receiveBytes = new byte[MAXIMUM_PACKET_SIZE];
        DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket( receiveBytes, 0, MAXIMUM_PACKET_SIZE );
        ByteBuffer receiveBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap( receiveBytes );
        receiveBuffer.limit( 0 );

        ByteBuffer emptyBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate( 0 );

        byte[] sendData = new byte[32768];
        DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket( sendData, 0, 32768 );
        ByteBuffer sendBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap( sendData );

        while( true ) {
            SSLEngineResult.HandshakeStatus hs = engine.getHandshakeStatus();
            switch( hs ) {
                case NEED_UNWRAP:
                case NEED_UNWRAP_AGAIN:
                    if( !receiveBuffer.hasRemaining() && hs != SSLEngineResult.HandshakeStatus.NEED_UNWRAP_AGAIN ) {
                        socket.receive( receivePacket );
                        receiveBuffer.position( 0 );
                        receiveBuffer.limit( receivePacket.getLength() );
                    }
                    checkStatus( engine.unwrap( receiveBuffer, emptyBuffer ) );
                    break;
                case NEED_WRAP:
                    checkStatus( engine.wrap( emptyBuffer, sendBuffer.clear() ) );
                    sendPacket.setLength( sendBuffer.position() );
                    socket.send( sendPacket );
                    break;
                case NEED_TASK:
                    Runnable runnable;
                    while( (runnable = engine.getDelegatedTask()) != null ) {
                        runnable.run();
                    }
                    break;
                case NOT_HANDSHAKING:
                    return;
                default:
                    // should never occur
                    throw new SSLException( "handshake error " + hs );
            }
        }
    } catch( Exception ex ) {
        throw ErrorCode.throwAny( ex );
    }
}

private void checkStatus( SSLEngineResult engineResult ) throws IOException {
    if( engineResult.getStatus() != SSLEngineResult.Status.OK ) {
        throw new SSLException( "handshake error " + engineResult.getStatus() + " with handshake state " + engineResult.getHandshakeStatus() );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use DTLS from native library like mbedtls.
Here is a library that exposes kotlin (java compatible) API: https://github.com/open-coap/kotlin-mbedtls.

Comment: Yes that is an option but that is not what my question was about . It was about not using any library. And in my case IoT a native lib was completely out of the question. But thanks for the tip.